# AttributeError: 'PdfPage' object has no attribute 'render_topil'

Tags: python, pdf

I am using pypdfium2 version 4.5.0, I am facing this problem

I want to make use of this render_topil

```
pdf = pdfium.PdfDocument(pdf_path)
page = pdf.get_page(0)
pil_image = page.render_topil(scale = 300/72)
image_name =f"Images/{image_name}.jpg"
pil_image.save(image_name)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ OP Would have been good if you had mentioned the actuall problem (attribute error, render_topil not available anymore), this makes it easier for others to understand.

Answer (score 6):

Pypdfium2 version 4 removed the `render_topil` method. As of version 4.9.0 the correct way to convert a Pypdfium2 Page object to PIL image following your code snippet is:

```
pdf = pdfium.PdfDocument(pdf_path)
page = pdf.get_page(0)
pil_image = page.render(scale = 300/72).to_pil()
image_name =f"Images/{image_name}.jpg"
pil_image.save(image_name)
```

Comment: Not just deprecated, actually removed.